# Pandas generating column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
from    to  

5   7   

8   10
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
from    to  zip_1   zip_2   zip_3   zip_4

5   8   5   6   7   8

9   10  9   10
```

I tried the following code but resulted in an error.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    zip_index = 0
    colName = 'zip' + '_' + str(zip_index)
    while row[colName] != row.To: 
        zip_index = zip_index + 1
        NewCol = 'zip' + '_' + str(zip_index)
        row[NewCol] = row[colName] + 1
        colName = NewCol
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Your expecting output misses value, Also You did not explained where does the new values comes frmo, how they are generated ?

Comment: Why do the "from" and "to" column values change from input to output? If that is expected what is the logic behind the change?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x["from"], x["to"] + 1), dtype = "float16"), axis = 1)

df2.columns += 1
df2 = df2.add_prefix("zip_")

df_final = pd.concat([df,df2], axis = 1)
#   from  to  zip_1  zip_2  zip_3  zip_4
#0     5   8    5.0    6.0    7.0    8.0
#1     9  10    9.0   10.0    NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"from":[5,7],"to":[9,10]})

   from  to
0   5     9
1   7    10
```

step 1: add your list in new columns:

```
df['r'] = df.apply(lambda x: [i for i in range (x['from'],x['to'])], axis=1 )        


    from    to   r
0   5        9   [5, 6, 7, 8]
1   7       10   [7, 8, 9]
```

step 3: explode

```
df.explode('r')


   from to  r
0   5   9   5
0   5   9   6
0   5   9   7
0   5   9   8
1   7   10  7
1   7   10  8
1   7
```

step 4: groupby and apply lambda such that:

```
df.explode('r').groupby(['from','to'])['r'].apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index()

   from   to    0   1   2   3
0   5      9    5   6   7   8
1   7     10    7   8   9   NaN
```

step 5: change column names:

```
df.add_prefix("zip_").rename(columns={'zip_from':'from','zip_to':'to'})

    from    to  zip_0   zip_1   zip_2   zip_3
0   5        9   5      6          7    8
1   7       10   7      8          9    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range()`, `to_list()` and `pd.concat()` to get this done.

There is a shorter way to do it but here's how I would do it.

- **Step 1:** create a range with `from` and `to` values
- **Step 2:** Convert the range values into a new DataFrame using
  `to_list()`. Make sure you `fillna(' ')` as some values will be NaNs
- **Step 3:** Update column name to zip_x where x is 1 thru n
- **Step 4:** drop `df['temp']` as you don't need this anymore
- **Step 5:** Concatenate both dataframes with axis=1

The full code is as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'from':[5,9],'to':[8,10]})

df['temp'] = [list(range(i, j+1)) for i, j in df.values]

#if you use import numpy as np, you can do:
#df['temp'] = [np.arange(i, j+1) for i, j in df.values]

dfX = pd.DataFrame(df.temp.to_list()).fillna('')

dfX.columns = [f'zip_{i+1}' for i in range(dfX.shape[1])]

df.drop('temp',axis=1,inplace=True)

df = pd.concat([df, dfX], axis=1)

print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

Original Dataframe:

```
   from  to
0     5   8
1     9  10
```

Updated Dataframe:

```
   from  to  zip_1  zip_2 zip_3 zip_4
0     5   8      5      6     7     8
1     9  10      9     10
```